# How I send http get , post requests from LARAVEL

Tags: php, json, http, curl

METHOD :POST
Ho I send data to this end point from php ?

```
{
    token: "token", 
    saledata: [
                {itemName: sample item 1, quantity: 2, itemTotal: 123.0},
                {itemName: sample item 3, quantity: 1, itemTotal: 123.0}
              ],
    total: 246.0, 
    saletime: 2020-04-18 22:00:40.044325
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/jwt_decode to parse JWT token

code snippet

```
import 'package:jwt_decode/jwt_decode.dart';

var token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImVtYWlsIjoiYUBiLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6ImI5ZDRiMTBmLTc4YWEtNGQzNy04OTRjLTQ0NjJkMGI2ZDUwYyIsImlhdCI6MTU4MzQ1OTk3OSwiZXhwIjoxNTgzNDYzNjE2fQ.D5cMT_nMLcTlZLgW7DbGs_cxZ8mpyOsAzI68JFPpboA';
var payload = Jwt.parseJwt(token);
print(payload);
print(payload["email"]);
```

output of full code

```
I/flutter (24248): {sub: 1234567890, name: John Doe, admin: true, email: a@b.com, jti: b9d4b10f-78aa-4d37-894c-4462d0b6d50c, iat: 1583459979, exp: 1583463616}
I/flutter (24248): a@b.com
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jwt_decode/jwt_decode.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(      
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    var token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImVtYWlsIjoiYUBiLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6ImI5ZDRiMTBmLTc4YWEtNGQzNy04OTRjLTQ0NjJkMGI2ZDUwYyIsImlhdCI6MTU4MzQ1OTk3OSwiZXhwIjoxNTgzNDYzNjE2fQ.D5cMT_nMLcTlZLgW7DbGs_cxZ8mpyOsAzI68JFPpboA';
    var payload = Jwt.parseJwt(token);
    print(payload);
    print(payload["email"]);
    setState(() {     
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(       
        child: Column(          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it help you. thanks.